# How is the tags system implemented?

Tags: discussion, tags, implementation

I like StackExchange's tag system.

[image: tag selection popup]

I want to know how it works. What libraries does it use?

Comment: It's combination of server side code used to store the tags in database (SQL Server backend), then jQuery AJAX to retrieve the tags per request, using C# as code behind. On second thought, this question is not dupe as I thought - reopening.

Comment: Yes, i think the question should be reopened. I did a lot of search but couldn't find the question post and the post that was referred to me was completely different with my question. Please do the honors by reopening my question.

Comment: Actually it's too broad. (used my vote already though)

Comment: Broad??? It's my description... I don't think it was tooo broad.... Can please specify why it looks broad...

Comment: First vote was too broad, but here we are

Comment: @gimibarak "or good answers would be too long for this format" might apply here. Like I said in the first comment, it's jQuery in client side (which you can see yourself) and C# in the server side, taking data from SQL Server database, where the code is not public. There is no additional library, it's all custom code written by SE developers.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard thank you, good to know the way tags were developed. I m trying to develop such of descriptive tags and just want to know it

Comment: @gimibarak you won't get the full code used here, so better try something of your own and if facing a problem, well, you already know Stack Overflow. ;)

Comment: Hey i dint ask for code dude....

Comment: IMO this is off topic for MSO, it's "how to (fully) implement a tagging system" that just so happens to use SE as an example. It's just a normal SO question.